# cx_Freeze app cannot find tk.tcl

Tags: python, tkinter, cx-freeze

I would like to distribute a tkinter app by using cx_Freeze.

- I can run the myapp.py from command line.
- cx_Freeze creates a folder named "exe.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.4", and the osx exe works from here.
- The osx exe from within myapp.app yields the following error:

  ```
  `tkinter.TclError: Can't find a usable tk.tcl in the following directories:` 
  ....    

  This probably means that tk wasn't installed properly.
  ```

Here is my stripped-down setup.py

```
build_exe_options = {"modules": ["tkinter", "time", "requests", "threading", "os"]}

setup(name="myapp",
      option={"build_exe": build_exe_options},
      executables=[Executable("myapp.py",
                              base=base)]
      )
```

Edit: I attempted this with python 2.7, and it works. The line "This probably means that tk wasn't installed properly" is likely correct.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem on mac Yosemite. The system python is 2.7 and I'm using python3. I found that python2.7 build successfully with tkinter but 3.4 does not.

Haven't figured out how to make python3.4 work yet.